# I have taken following code from the book but not understand from numerous research

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I got it from a textbook named Automate The Boring Stuff With Python. I have done lot of research but still not able to understand. Can anyone provide clarification stepwise?

```
    allGuests = {'Alice': {'apples': 5, 'pretzels': 12},
                'Bob': {'ham sandwiches': 3, 'apples': 2},
                'Carol': {'cups': 3, 'apple pies': 1}}

        def totalBrought(guests, item):
            numBrought = 0
            for k, v in guests.items():
                numBrought = numBrought + v.get(item, 0)
           return numBrought
    print('Number of things being brought:')
    print(' - Apples' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'apples')))
    print(' - Cups' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'cups')))
    print(' - Cakes ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests,'cakes')))
    print(' - Ham Sandwiches ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'ham sandwiches')))
    print(' - Apple Pies' + str(totalBrought(allGuests,'apple pies')))
```

Output:

```
Number of things being brought:
- Apples 7
- Cups 3
- Cakes 0
- Ham Sandwiches 3
- Apple Pies
1
```

Comment: Since you haven't done a lot of research yet, please try to study Python data structures and in particular dictionaries to understand what's going on here. For example here: https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries
There's also a list of good resources on Python on Stackoverflow that will help you get started, see: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info

Comment: Are you running this under Python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: I am running this code in python 3.x

Comment: Please ask about a single *specific* part you don't understand. For instance, if it's the line `numBrought = 0` that is puzzling you: it assigns a value of `0` to a variable named `numBrought`. If you need such an explanation for *every single line*, then you are better off first learning Python from scratch.

Comment: I have doubt in print command how it is retrieved data from the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# this is dictionary. format is {<key>: <value>},
# in this code it is nested dictionary {<dict1>: {<innerkey>: <value>}}
allGuests = {'Alice': {'apples': 5, 'pretzels': 12},
             'Bob': {'ham sandwiches': 3, 'apples': 2},
             'Carol': {'cups': 3, 'apple pies': 1}}


# in this function you will receive nested dictionary (guests)
# and the value (item) which will be searched as key in dictionary
def totalBrought(guests, item):
    numBrought = 0  # this is return value and set as zero initially
    for k, v in guests.items():  # for loop to iterate each dictionary element and its nested elements, items() will return elements of dictionary
        numBrought = numBrought + v.get(item, 0)  # here you check whether your value is exist in inner dictionary.
                                                  # if so, you will get its value (integer in here) with get() function and sum them continuously
    return numBrought  # and return result


print('Number of things being brought:')
print(' - Apples' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'apples')))  # in total you have 7 apples ('apples': 5 + 'apples': 2)
print(' - Cups' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'cups')))
print(' - Cakes ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'cakes')))
print(' - Ham Sandwiches ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'ham sandwiches')))
print(' - Apple Pies' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'apple pies')))
```